# How to pass closure as a variable?

Tags: swift, closures

I have following code from playground:

```
class MyButton {
    var pressed: (() -> Void)?
    
    func press() {
        pressed?()
    }
}

class SomeView {
    var buttonDidPressed: (() -> Void)?
    
    let button = MyButton()
    
    init() {
        button.pressed = buttonDidPressed
    }
    
    func press() {
        button.press()
    }
}

let view = SomeView()

view.buttonDidPressed = {
    print("pressed")
}

view.press()
```

`MyButton` has closure `pressed` which is executed when `press` is called. In `SomeView`s init, I assign value to that `pressed` closure. Of course, at the init, it is `nil`. But after initialization of `SomeView`, I assign value to that `buttonDidPressed` closure. Because, closures are reference type, when `view.press` is called, `buttonDidPressed` should not be nil. But, anyway, my print is not executed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you want to achieve:

```
class SomeView {
    var buttonDidPressed: (() -> Void)? = nil {
       didSet {
          button.pressed = buttonDidPressed
       }
    }
    
    let button = MyButton()
    
    func press() {
        button.press()
    }
}
```

---

The reason your code isn't working is because in the `SomeView.init`, `buttonDidPressed` is `nil` - i.e. it's a lack of reference. So:

```
buttonDidPressed = nil
button.pressed = buttonDidPressed 
// is equivalent to
button.pressed = nil
```

Assigning a new (or different) reference to `buttonDidPressed` later doesn't change the `button.pressed` property.

Answer (score 2):

You first initialize `SomeView` (the `init` function gets called) and then you set the `buttonDidPressed` property. So, the `buttonDidPressed` property has your closure but never passed it to `MyButton` instance.

You can use `didSet` to update it immediately:

```
class SomeView {
    var buttonDidPressed: (() -> Void)? {
        didSet {
            button.pressed = buttonDidPressed
        }
    }
    
    let button = MyButton()
    
    func press() {
        button.press()
    }
}
```

**Update**: You can also pass your closure in the initializer of `SomeView` like this:

```
class SomeView {
    let button = MyButton()
    
    init(buttonDidPressed: (() -> Void)?) {
        button.pressed = buttonDidPressed
    }
    
    func press() {
        button.press()
    }
}

let view = SomeView {
    print("pressed")
}

view.press()
```

Comment: But why? Closure is reference type. I assigned it later, after init. It should point to the same address in memory

Comment: @neo You are confusing what is a reference type and what is a variable.

Comment: Yes, I am wrong. But where exactly? I created `SomeView` and after assigned a value to the closure buttonDidPressed. And only after that I called press. But print is not executing.

Comment: @neo the first time, you set `pressed` property of `MyButton` to point at `nil`. That will not change if `buttonDidPressed` later points to an actual value.

Comment: it is a good example being closures are reference type putting [weak self] by using we are weakly reference, good explanations and questions thanks fellows

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is better to explain with this issue by using binding, Let`s say :

```
class Sekoya<T> {
typealias Listener = (T) -> Void
var listenerHolder: Listener?
var value: T {
    didSet {
        listenerHolder?(value) // when value change listenerHolder triger
    }
}

init(_ value: T) {
    self.value = value
}

func bind(listener: Listener?) {
    
    self.listenerHolder = listener // referencing listener my closure variable in SomeView Class
    listener?(value)
    
}
}
```

Lets use this binding at the another class:

```
 let sekoyaInt = Sekoya(25)
    sekoyaInt.bind {
            print("value changed: \($0)")
        }
```

Whenever you change the value your reference closure will be trigger and value will be change and it prints value

Comment: You created another function just to initialize closure. I would want to avoid such a function. I tried to implement it on init.